# what should be there in refresh plan in saleforce

Tags: refresh

I want a document of a Refresh plan for in saleforce . Can someone share, let me know what exactly would need to be in there.

Please let me know the checklist what all should this document have

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you mean by refresh plan? Are you talking about a sandbox refresh?

Comment: It is hard to tell what needs to be done in your organisation when a refresh occurs, depeding on the type of sandbox, are there emails that need to be reset, web service endpoints that need to be changed to dev,...